# Dynamically change src path in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to dynamically change the path of my `<img>`'s `src` in Vue:

```html
<template>
  <img :src="'../../assets/logo/'+LogoSrc()" alt="logo black" :height="height+'px'" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Logo",
  props: {
    logoColor: {
      type: String,
      default: "dark"
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 10
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  methods: {
    LogoSrc() {
      if (this.logoColor === "dark") {
        return "logo-black.svg";
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

[image: image not loadng]

Though the path is right, the image is still not loading. I tried using `src` without the `v-bind` with path being the same (`../../assets/logo/logo-black.svg`), and it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic URLs, use `require()`:

```html
<img :src="require('../../assets/logo/' + LogoSrc())">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-heisenberg-0umhb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Make it a computed value:

```
<template>
  <img :src="LogoSrc" alt="logo black" :height="height+'px'" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Logo",
  props: {
    logoColor: {
      type: String,
      default: "dark"
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      default: 10
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },

  computed: {
    LogoSrc() {
      if (this.logoColor === "dark") 
        return "../../assets/logo/logo-black.svg";
      
      return "";
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```